# Running the XAVWSample code from the UPS Developer

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run the sample project XAVWSClient that came with my developers' kit.  I have an AccessLicenseNumber, username, and password.

I execute:

```
XAVResponse xavResponse = xavSvc.ProcessXAV ( xavRequest );
```

It fails with this error:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Is there anything else I need to do to get this sample to work?

Thanks in advance,
Paul